# Quantum Resistant Algorithms and types: PKE vs PKEs vs KEM vs KEMs vs DSS

Tags: public-key, post-quantum-cryptography

I am trying to wrap my head around the second round Quantum Resistant Algorithm candidates currently under the [*NIST PQC Effort*](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography).

**Can someone verify if the following is a correct summary of the 17-Public Key Encryption and Key Establishment Mechanisms versus 9-Digital Signature Algorithms and their types?** Specifically, I am asking if I got the classifications of either KEM, KEMs, PKE, PKEs, PKE & KEM, PKEs and KEMs and DSS all correct as defined below.

We have Key Encapsulation Mechanism (KEM) (KEM for a single one and KEMS for multiple), Public Key Encryption (PKE for a single one and PKEs for multiple) and Digital Signature Schemes (DSS).

**PKEs and KEMs (17):**

- BIKE - KEM
- Classic McEliece - KEM
- CRYSTALS-KYBER - KEMs
- FrodoKEM - KEM
- HQC - PKE
- LAC - PKE
- LEDAcrypt (LEDAKem / LEDApkc) - PKE and KEM
- Newhope - KEMs
- NTRU - PKE and KEM
- NTRU Prime - KEMs
- NTS-KEM - KEM
- ROLLO (LAKE, LOCKER, Ouroboros-R) - KEMs
- Round5 (HILA5 and Round2) - PKE and KEM
- RQC - PKE
- SABER - PKEs and KEMs
- SIKE - KEM
- Three Bears - KEM

**DSSs (9):**

- CRYSTALS - DILITHIUM
- FALCON
- GEMSS
- LUOV
- MQDSS
- Picnic
- qTESLA
- Rainbow
- SPHINCS+

Comment: Are you just asking if your list is complete?

Comment: @forest: I am asking if I got the classifications of either KEM, KEMs, PKE, PKEs, PKE & KEM, PKEs and KEMs and DSS all correct.